# Calculate percentiles ignoring missing values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null, percentile

I have a PySpark dataframe with columns `ID` and `BALANCE`.
I am trying to bucket the column `balance` into 100 percentile (1-100%) buckets and calculate how many IDs fall in each bucket.

I cannot use anything related to RDD, I can only use PySpark syntax. I've tried the code below.

```py
w = Window.orderBy(df.BALANCE)
test = df.withColumn('percentile_col', F.percent_rank().over(w))
```

I am hoping to get a new column that automatically calculates the percentile of each data point in BALANCE column and ignoring the missing value.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.1+** has `unionByName` which has an optional argument `allowMissingColumns`. This makes it easier.

Test data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = spark.range(12).withColumn(
    'balance',
    F.when(~F.col('id').isin([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), F.col('id') + 500))
df.show()
#+---+-------+
#| id|balance|
#+---+-------+
#|  0|   null|
#|  1|   null|
#|  2|   null|
#|  3|   null|
#|  4|   null|
#|  5|    505|
#|  6|    506|
#|  7|    507|
#|  8|    508|
#|  9|    509|
#| 10|    510|
#| 11|    511|
#+---+-------+
```

`percent_rank` will give you exact percentiles - results may have many numbers after the decimal point. That's why `percent_rank` alone may not provide what you want.

```py
df = (
    df.filter(~F.isnull('balance'))
    .withColumn('percentile', F.percent_rank().over(W.orderBy('balance')))
    .unionByName(df.filter(F.isnull('balance')), True)
)
df.show()
#+---+-------+-------------------+
#| id|balance|         percentile|
#+---+-------+-------------------+
#|  5|    505|                0.0|
#|  6|    506|0.16666666666666666|
#|  7|    507| 0.3333333333333333|
#|  8|    508|                0.5|
#|  9|    509| 0.6666666666666666|
#| 10|    510| 0.8333333333333334|
#| 11|    511|                1.0|
#|  0|   null|               null|
#|  1|   null|               null|
#|  2|   null|               null|
#|  3|   null|               null|
#|  4|   null|               null|
#+---+-------+-------------------+
```

The following should work. Rounding step is added.

```py
pr = F.percent_rank().over(W.orderBy('balance'))
df = (
    df.filter(~F.isnull('balance'))
    .withColumn('bucket', F.when(pr == 0, 1).otherwise(F.ceil(pr * 100)))
    .unionByName(df.filter(F.isnull('balance')), True)
)
df.show()
#+---+-------+------+
#| id|balance|bucket|
#+---+-------+------+
#|  5|    505|     1|
#|  6|    506|    17|
#|  7|    507|    34|
#|  8|    508|    50|
#|  9|    509|    67|
#| 10|    510|    84|
#| 11|    511|   100|
#|  0|   null|  null|
#|  1|   null|  null|
#|  2|   null|  null|
#|  3|   null|  null|
#|  4|   null|  null|
#+---+-------+------+
```

---

You may also consider `ntile`. Every value is added to one of n "buckets".

When n=100 (test table has less than 100 items, so only the first "buckets" get values):

```py
df = (
    df.filter(~F.isnull('balance'))
    .withColumn('ntile_100', F.ntile(100).over(W.orderBy('balance')))
    .unionByName(df.filter(F.isnull('balance')), True)
)
df.show()
#+---+-------+---------+
#| id|balance|ntile_100|
#+---+-------+---------+
#|  5|    505|        1|
#|  6|    506|        2|
#|  7|    507|        3|
#|  8|    508|        4|
#|  9|    509|        5|
#| 10|    510|        6|
#| 11|    511|        7|
#|  0|   null|     null|
#|  1|   null|     null|
#|  2|   null|     null|
#|  3|   null|     null|
#|  4|   null|     null|
#+---+-------+---------+
```

When n=4:

```py
df = (
    df.filter(~F.isnull('balance'))
    .withColumn('ntile_100', F.ntile(4).over(W.orderBy('balance')))
    .unionByName(df.filter(F.isnull('balance')), True)
)
df.show()
#+---+-------+---------+
#| id|balance|ntile_100|
#+---+-------+---------+
#|  5|    505|        1|
#|  6|    506|        1|
#|  7|    507|        2|
#|  8|    508|        2|
#|  9|    509|        3|
#| 10|    510|        3|
#| 11|    511|        4|
#|  0|   null|     null|
#|  1|   null|     null|
#|  2|   null|     null|
#|  3|   null|     null|
#|  4|   null|     null|
#+---+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.
We are first checking if the df.Balance column has Null values. If it has Null values we are displaying None. Else the percent_rank() function gets applied.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.orderBy(df.BALANCE)

test = df.withColumn('percentile_col',when(df.BALANCE.isNull(), lit(None)).otherwise(F.percent_rank().over(w)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not ignore nulls. This just hides `percent_rank` result for entries where BALANCE is null.